# Why is ImagePicker unable to pick multiple images

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-gallery, imagepicker

I'm trying to pick multiple images at once using the [image_picker 0.7.5+3](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package
so my code is simple , just one line to open the gallery to select from it

```
final images = await ImagePicker.platform.pickMultiImage();
```

but it's showing this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AWJZ.png)

i tried running flutter clean and deleting the app from emulator and retarting everything but it's the same problem,

note : using `final images = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);` it allows me to choose an image without any problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything in their [API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/image_picker/latest/image_picker/ImagePicker-class.html) for `pickMultiImage`. I don't think it exists, unfortunately. There's a package called [images_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/images_picker), maybe that helps you.

Answer (score 2):

```
final result = await ImagePicker().pickMultiImage(
  imageQuality: 70,
  maxWidth: 1440,

);
```

This should work as usual. If you are testing on android emulator and the default file manager, you have to long press the first image to multi-select.

Answer (score 1):

Try a long click on one image, then it will let you pick multiple images.